# How to access component data from slot?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

It's not working: https://jsfiddle.net/2ouxsuLh/

```
var myAwesomeComponent = Vue.component({
    template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  data: function () {
    return {
        myAwesomeData: 'Message'
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  template: '<my-awesome-component>{{ myAwesomeData }}</my-awesome-component>',
  components: {
    myAwesomeComponent: myAwesomeComponent
  }
});
```

It's happening because myAwesomeData isn't defined in parent component, and we can't use component's variables with .

Instead of this, we need to create our own component and pass it inside my-awesome-component like this: https://jsfiddle.net/simplesmiler/5p420nbe/

But it's overhead, isn't it?

For example, in angular we can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9609/
It's much simplier.

We can do something like this in Vue?

Comment: Sorry about  links, site restrict.

Comment: no, I just posted an edit for that. Youi just have to do it correctly

Comment: Can you show me this example in correct Vue-way?

Comment: Why is `myAwesomeData` in the child? Do you need `myAwesomeData` to live with the data you're passing in through the slot? You could do `<div><slot></slot> {{ myAwesomeData }}</div>` in the template. If you actually need `myAwesomeData` in the slot chances are it should not be in the child.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) to approximate your Angular example. The child defines a `slot` in its template, and as an attribute of the `slot` tag, it defines data that will be available to the parent. The parent passes a template in as the slot filler. The template can refer to the data defined by the child through the `scope` attribute.

```js
var myAwesomeComponent = {
  template: '<div><slot myAwesomeData="Directive Message"></slot></div>'
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    test: myAwesomeComponent
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <test>
    <template scope="props">
      {{ props.myAwesomeData }}
    </template>
  </test>
</div>
```